# CSS Selector for all the buttons with class

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a model for my landing page and want to trigger a single model for by multiple buttons. But I am unable to to use every button, it only works for the first button.

Markup

```
 <button class="trigger" class="pricing_button single_button" >BUY</button>
```

JS Script

```
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
    var trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
    var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

    function toggleModal() {
        modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
    }

    function windowOnClick(event) {
        if (event.target === modal) {
            toggleModal();
        }
    }
    trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
    closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
    window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
```

My code is only working for the first button. I checked online and found `document.querySelectorAll` but it also doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You have to use `querySelectorAll` and after that, you must traverse all of the elements you've gathered in the variable:
1. `var trigger = document.querySelectorAll(".trigger");`
2. `trigger.forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener('click', toggleModal));`

Comment: Hey, This did make all the button to work, but my close button doesn't seem to work now?

Comment: @Bhanu I think my answer should make it work for both close and trigger as both of these do same task

Comment: @GauravSaraswat yes Gaurav, It did, Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, you are looking for `document.querySelectorAll` **api**.
below code should help:

```
var allTriggers = document.querySelectorAll(".trigger, .close-button");
Array.from(triggers).formEach(trigger => {
  trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
});
```

Comment: One more thing, how can I make the close action work with esc button also?

Comment: For that you should look at `keyboardEvent` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. Using the above code, I am not able to close the modal by clicking outside of the modal?

Comment: For outside click. you need to add event on `document` and `check if event target likes outside modal `and close it seperately